# Notation of a function that Maps two sets into a Matrix

Tags: matrices, functions, notation

Given two sets $P, V$ a function $f(t)$ takes any element that belongs to $ P $ or $ V $ e.g. $ t \in P \cup V$ returns a matrix of $ 2 $ columns and $K$ rows. What is the proper notation to express this function $f$ ? something like this ?

$$ f: P\cup V \rightarrow ? X_{j,j} \;\forall j = 2, i=k  $$

$ K $ is finite, however not same for all $t \in P \cup V$ e.g. $K$ for $t_{1}$ and $K$ for $t_{2}$ may vary $ \{t_{1}, t_{2}\} \in P\cup V $ like the following.

$$ f(t_{1}) = \begin{bmatrix}
    v_{1}^{min} & v_{1}^{max} \\
    v_{2}^{min} & v_{2}^{max} \\
    v_{3}^{min} & v_{3}^{max}
\end{bmatrix}, f(t_{2}) = \begin{bmatrix}
    v_{1}^{min} & v_{1}^{max} \\
    v_{2}^{min} & v_{2}^{max} 
\end{bmatrix},  f(t_{3}) = \begin{bmatrix}
    v_{1}^{min} & v_{1}^{max}
\end{bmatrix}$$

I can also express the matrix as a combination of two vectors $f_{min}$ and $f_{max}$ Then also How to express that number of rows of the matrix varies for $t_{i}$

And how to do the same with a Vector instead of matrix ? should I use $ V $ instead of $ M $ ?

-- Edit --

with the comments of @Jp McCarthy 
is it like $ M_{2\times \vert f_{t_{i}} \vert}(\mathbb{Z}) \;\forall\; t_{i} \; \in (P \cup V)$ However this notation is not sometimes readable due to reduced font size

Comment: $f:(P\cup V)\rightarrow M_{2\times K}(\mathbb{C})$ is one possible notation.

Comment: What is C ? and is the arrow style correct ?

Comment: The arrow style is fine. $M_{2\times K}(\mathbb{C})$ is the set of matrices of size $2\times K$ with entries in the set of complex numbers. If your matrix entries are real numbers you could use $\mathbb{R}$ instead. What type of numbers are your matrix entries?

Comment: Hm Real Numbers.

Comment: ...well then use $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{C}$ (although $\mathbb{C}$ contains $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: What if $ K $ is derived ? e.g. K is not constant different elements of P or V will have different K ? something like $ k = \vert f(x) \vert $

Comment: You're going to have to give more context because you have two $f$s now... suppose $K$ depends on a parameter $\lambda$ such that $K=K(\lambda)$... then you kind of have problems unless you can embed small matrices into a larger ones... you need to give more context and maybe you don't even need matrices.

Comment: question updated

Comment: ....that isn't context...

Comment: edited again....